# PHP MsSQL PDO or API

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I usually work with PHP MySQL and resultantly, my knowledge with MsSQL is somewhat limited. I am about to write a class that makes executing MsSQL queries much easier for myself and my associates. However, in my research, I have found that I have two options of how to connect to an MsSQL database; I can either use the PHP PDO Library or the SQLSRV API. The latter seems the better option for me as I am unfamiliar with the PDO library and how it works, although, I would be willing to learn more about the PDO library if it is the much better choice.

So effectively, I would simply like to know which option is better for communicating with an MsSQL database using PHP?

In addition, is anybody familiar with a good site with examples and documentation of the API? The Microsoft website is good, but somewhat biased and limited.

Any help much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend you to learn PDO.

Where MySQL(i) is only for MySQL, and SQLSRV API is only for MsSQL, PDO is for around 20 different database engines. Plus, it's object oriented and supports named parameters in prepared statements.

**[See this great article (it's about PDO vs MySQLi, but the arguments there are valid)](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/)**

Comment: That is very helpful, thank you. Before I proceed to learning how to use the PDO library, are there built in methods that do the same as the general MsSQL and MySQL functions. e.g. mysql_real_escape_string? This is not a problem if not as I can write them myself, but it would be nicer. What is the benefit of named parameters?

Comment: @BenCarey the answer to your second question is the answer to your first question ! Read the security section of the linked doc

Comment: Well, let's say you want to select from a table based on user input. In PDO, you can use `SELECT id FROM table WHERE input = :input`, you can imagine the benefit when you have, let's say 5 fields? 10?. You don't need to remember which `?` is which like you would with MySQLi, plus you have the added flexibility when you don't need to remember the order of the strings/integers.

Comment: @ManseUK yup, I noticed that! :-)! Truth, that all makes sense and I am sure a lot of people find it very helpful, however, I dont think it applies to me because I will simply be gathering data from HTML fields, validating them with PHP and inserting/updating the database. Maybe I misunderstood what you are saying if that is not relevant. If so, could you post a small code example in your answer? :-D

Comment: @Truth Ah, I understand now! Got it working, let the training begin! One last thing, the website you have linked to says not to use quote, however do the prepare and execute methods both escape the queries?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to write a wrapper class to SQL may i suggest something like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) instead. Its an Object Relational Mapper (ORM) it uses Objects to represent records in a database and a Database Abstraction Layer(DBAL) that uses PDO :

> Object relational mapper (ORM) for PHP that sits on top of a powerful
>   database abstraction layer (DBAL). One of its key features is the
>   option to write database queries in a proprietary object oriented SQL
>   dialect called Doctrine Query Language (DQL), inspired by Hibernates
>   HQL. This provides developers with a powerful alternative to SQL that
>   maintains flexibility without requiring unnecessary code duplication.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I do not like using third party libraries and API's for many reasons. I respect that Doctrine is probably awesome, but I much prefer writing the classes myself because then I am completely familiar with how they work. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Truth that PDO is a more portable API than SQLSRV and therefore generally a better choice.

However there is one bad thing about PDO: insofar as I can tell, it always returns data as type "string", regardless of the datatype in the originating database. Various other SO posts on why PDO is like this boil down to "because that's the way it is on PHP". Maybe so, but it's still gross: returning datetimes or floating point numbers as strings wastes bandwidth, reduces precision, and introduces problems with internationalization due to differences in decimal points and date formats. Yuck.

I'd been planning to use the PDO driver for the obvious reasons, but now I'm taking a look at the SQLSRV driver since it preserves data types.