# PDO To Connect to MSSQL Over MSSQL_* Functions

Tags: php, database, sybase

There is a range of `mssql_*` Which are not in the depreciation process.

They work the same as `mysql_*` functions; they need to me manually escaped, please find the link to the manual below:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php

MSSQL_* Functions was apart of `php5-mssql` but have now been moved into `php5-sybase`

Furthermore, using PDO for your Database Construct, is available but is **experimental**
http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php

But my overall question, from the fact that PDO/MySQLI is being pushed as main database communication solution, should I stop using the functions `mssql_*`

Or is it possible for:

PDO Connection:

```
$dsn = 'mssql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

But if this process is still listed as experimental, should developers using `Microsoft SQL Server` for their databases, wait till this extension is *stable for MSSQL Servers*

So at the end of the  day, PDO Extension or MSSQL_* Functions even though they are not depreciated.. If so, why?

Answer (score 15):

### My Own Opinion

I have been using `PDO` to connect to a `MSSQL` database for over a year now and so far I have found absolutely no issues.

In fact, I looked into using the `mssql_*` functions before migrating to `PDO`, and came to the conclusion that they were a much less reliable, not to mention, insecure way of connecting to a `MSSQL` Database.

### Logically

From a logical point of view, `PDO` is also the better option as it only takes a few tweaks to the code in order to change from `MSSQL` to `MySQL`.

I wrote a wrapper class for the PDO class that makes connecting to these databases very easy.

Consider this as an example:

```
<?php

// +------------------------------------------------------------------------+
// | class.mssql.php                                                        |
// +------------------------------------------------------------------------+
// | Copyright (c) Company Ltd 2013. All rights reserved.                   |
// | Version       1.0                                                      |
// | Last modified 30/01/2013                                               |
// | Email         email@company.co.uk                                      |
// | Web           http://www.company.co.uk                                 |
// +------------------------------------------------------------------------+

// Make sure the SQL class is included
require_once("class.sql.php");

/*
 * Class mssql
 *
 * @version   1.0
 * @author    Ben Carey <email@company.co.uk>
 * @copyright Company Ltd
 *
*/
 
class mssql extends sql{
    
    /**
     * Initialize the object and set/reset all variables
     *
     * This function is called when the object is constructed
     *
     * @access private
     */
    function __construct(&$memcache){
        
        // Call the sql construct
        parent::__construct($memcache);
        
        // Global MsSQL defaults
        $this->query_escaper_left               = "[";
        $this->query_escaper_right          = "]";
        $this->connection_engine                = "sqlsrv";
        $this->connection_parameter_host        = "server";
        $this->connection_parameter_database    = "Database";
        $this->select_db_function               = "db_name()";
    }
}

?>
```

Anything that is unique to `MSSQL` is defined in this extension and then passed up to the parent class `class.sql.php`. The beauty of PDO is that the code in the file `class.sql.php` does not have to be altered in any way to work with any database (or, all the databases that I have tried thus far).

So all that is needed here is a small extension for each database type and it will work.

Whereas, with the native `mssql_*` functions, if you were to decide to change database for any particular reason, you would have to rewrite everything. Not to mention, you would have to use PDO for MySQL anyway given that the `mysql_*` functions are now deprecated.

### My Testing with PDO

I have been running complex stored procedures, with `INPUT PARAMETERS`, `OUTPUT PARAMETERS`, `INOUT PARAMETERS`, on databases with 100,000,000+ records in them. These have worked absolutely flawlessly, and continue to do so!

### References

Another reason not to use the `mssql_*` functions is that they are no longer supported on Windows with PHP version 5.3 or later:

**[See Here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mssql.php)**

The SyBase Extension falls under the same category as the `mssql_*` functions. They are procedural, impractical and not portable at all!

### Functionality

At a glance, I have noticed that none of these extensions have a function equivalent to the `mysql_real_escape_string()` function. Whereas, in PDO, there is no need for this

### Conclusion

It goes without saying that I am a moral PDO supporter (and this has only come after using it for 1 year!). That is not to say I will not listen to other peoples opinions on the `mssql_*` functions, it will just be very hard to persuade me, and I think most people, that these functions can even compete the PDO.

So to conclude, in my opinion, PDO is the way forward for the following key reasons:

1. It is very portable, easy to switch to different databases with minimal code
2. It is secure without the need of functions like `mysql_real_escape_string()`
3. It is fast becoming the norm for developers
4. If you do not have experience with Object Oriented Programming, then it is an excellent introduction
5. It comes pre-installed with most PHP Packages
6. It can execute comples queries with ease, including stored procedures
7. **After benchmarking it with a MySQL database against the old deprecated `mysql_*` functions, it has proved to be faster in a lot of cases, if not all cases.** - **[See Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9770560/is-the-pdo-library-faster-than-the-native-mysql-functions)**

I asked a similar question a while back, and the same conclusion was drawn:

**[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9716476/php-mssql-pdo-or-api)**

Comment: My bounty goes to you kind sir. I love your reply.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to explain your class a bit more?

Answer (score 4):

This could spark up a good debate. I guess the only way to test the stability of the PDO functions towards Microsoft SQL Servers, is to setup your own local testing zone and push the PDO Class to its abilities.

As you said, php5-sybase contains MSSQL Functions and are not in the deprecation process.

I guess it's down to what the developer feels comfortable with.

If you're happy with MSSQL_* Functions, then go ahead and use them, but there could be a possibility they will end up getting deprecated from PHP altogether in the near future -- it's happening with MySQL Functions.

Although, if you're looking for a change and new challenges, with added security from SQL Injection, then go ahead and try out the PDO compatibility with MSSQL Servers.

It's entirely down to you.

From my preference & and guess many other developers preference, I would say go for the PDO functions. I assume it would work as normal.

```
<?php
$dsn = 'mssql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

$Query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM Tbl WHERE `ID` = :id");
$Query ->bindParam(':id', $ID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$Query->execute();

// etc..
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

PDO is definitely the way to go and for linux users I stongly recommend going with the sybase connector and the the dblib DSN.

For ubuntu users with PHP7 it would be:

```
sudo apt-get install php-sybase freetds-common libsybdb5
```

And for connecting:

```
$db = new PDO("dblib: host=$hostname:$port; dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpassword);
```

And you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

PDO is the obvious choice with security in mind.  PDO code is portable - it can be adjusted to send information to a number of databases without having to change the function calls and only changing a few parameters.

The MSSQL class is not portable the way that PDO is portable.

PDO has excellent support for prepared statements while MSSQL has none.
PDO acts as an abstraction layer much like JDBC in Java and is portable.
PDO has support for transactions, is better for handling errors

Hope the answer is obvious!