# connect to ms sql server using php

Tags: php, sql

I have a shared windows web-hosting with Godaddy. i set up an MS SQL server database. i can connect to it very well using ASP. Now, i would like to connect to the same database using PHP.
I have tried these articles in vain; http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/3351/mysql-connection-string-with-php. 
I have tried Godaddy support but of late, they seem to have stopped email support.

Can anyone help me and point me in the right direction?
many thanx

EDIT: this is the code that i have adapted from Godaddy but it seems to work for MySQL and not MS SQL. How could i adapt it to work for connecting to Ms SQL server?

```
<?php
//Sample Database Connection Syntax for PHP and MySQL.

//Connect To Database

$hostname="my_host_name";
$username="my_dbusername";
$password="my_dbpassword";
$dbname="my_dbusername";
$usertable="my_tablename";
$yourfield = "myr_field";

mysql_connect($hostname,$username, $password) or die ("<html><script     language='JavaScript'>alert('Unable to connect to database! Please try again later.'),history.go(-1)</script></html>");
mysql_select_db($dbname);

# Check If Record Exists

$query = "SELECT * FROM $usertable";

$result = mysql_query($query);

if($result)
{
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$name = $row["$yourfield"];
echo "Name: ".$name."<br>";
}
}
?>
```

Thanx

Comment: [PDO](http://www.php.net/pdo) supports multiple drivers.

Comment: what is your code like?

Comment: Yeah. GoDaddy support takes years to reply.. Post your code and let see what we can do with it..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14299813/pdo-to-connect-to-mssql-over-mssql-functions