# Setting up a local call to DB with an online PHP file - trouble connecting

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

Trying to figure out how to connect to a local SQL Server with an online PHP file. However I am getting connection errors.

> Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: [2002] No
>   connection could be made because the target machine actively refused
>   it. (trying to connect via tcp://localhost:xxxx) in
>   E:\web\example.com\uploads\readDB.php on line 8

In particular I am having trouble trying to specify if, and where, I do the connection to the PC and then to the database with any associated passwords.

My current connection looks like this

```
 mysql_connect("localhost","the_sql_server_name\SQLEXPRESS","mysql"); 
 mysql_select_db("ACME") or die(mysql_error()); 
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM TradingAccount") 
 or die(mysql_error());
```

My server is run locally (sql server studio management 2012), and I am trying to connect to its specific DB called ACME, from the table TradingAccount.

Can someone show me how to connect to this local table successfully with PHP? I use Windows Authentication at the moment when I run the server as well, in case that matters.

I haven't been able to find any useful resources, and I have only ever used PHP to connect to online DB's as well, nothing locally before.

Comment: you are using mysql-* function with Microsoft SQL server which is incorrect, try to use PDO! see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14299813/pdo-to-connect-to-mssql-over-mssql-functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Problem is in this line:

```
mysql_connect("localhost","the_sql_server_name\SQLEXPRESS","mysql");
```

You wrote `the_sql_server_name\SQLEXPRESS` there. I don't understand why. The syntax of the method is:

```
mysql_connect("hostname", "username", "password");
```

For more information, visit the [PHP manual entry for mysql_connect](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-connect.php).