# How do I query MSSQL then display the result using php?

Tags: php, html, css, sql-server, iis

So a while back I created a batch script to query sql server and output the results as a text file then used php to read and display that file.  Now I want to use php to eliminate the use of the batch script.  But I cant seem to find any information to help me get started.   I went to https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php and tried to use an example listed from that and put it in my index.php and all it did was break the page.

I'm a noob when it comes to php, but was advised this is a more elegant solution to my problem. Yet given my limited experience I have no idea where to start.

Can anyone get me started in the right direction?

Comment: use pdo it's the best way i think

Comment: i think it's dublicated question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14299813/pdo-to-connect-to-mssql-over-mssql-functions

Comment: @MrLister I miss read the question. Just had MySQL on the brain.